# How can i create ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory dynamically by setting bean name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am trying to create ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory's. I need more than 10. I don't want to create these factories by hard coded with copy and paste one after the other. How can i create these dynamically by setting **custom bean name**?

```
     @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, MyDTO> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    // props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*"); // Allow deserialization of all packages
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MyDTO.class));
  }

@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyDTO>
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory1() {
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyDTO> factory =
          new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
      factory
          .getContainerProperties()
          .setIdleBetweenPolls(
              topicProperties
                  .getTopics()
                  .getSubTopics()
                  .get(TOPIC_1.getLabel())
                  .getPollIntervalMs());
      factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
      return factory;
    }
```

My listener:

```
  @KafkaListener(
      topics =
          "topic",
      containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory1", 
      groupId = "group")
  @Override
  public void consume1(MyDTO dto) {
    log.info("consumed {}", dto.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom BeanFactory implementation where you can create multiple beans of same kafka factory with different names. you can follow more details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-same-class-multiple-beans#2-custom-beanfactory-implementation)